# Django-rest-framework: disable nested fields

Tags: json, django, django-rest-framework

I'm working with Django REST Framework and I

I have a serializer called QuestionSerializer where I specified 3 fields that I need to have in my response: id, json and explanation.
Since I'm using JSONField in a PostgreSQL Database, my json field is a json stored inside the db and I render it using JSONSerializerField.

Here's my code:

```
class JSONSerializerField(serializers.Field):
    """ Serializer for JSONField -- required to make field writable"""
    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        return data
    def to_representation(self, value):
        return value

class QuestionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    content = JSONSerializerField(source='json')

    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ('id', 'content', 'explanation')
```

So, every time I'll use QuestionSerializer my response will be something like this:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "content": {
        "question": "question",
        "answers": [
            {"answer": "answer"},
            {"answer": "answer"},
            {"answer": "answer"},
            {"answer": "answer"},
            {"answer": "answer"}
        ],
    }
    "explanation": "explanation"
}
```

But I need to remove "content" field to have a response like:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "question": "question",
    "answers": [
        {"answer": "answer"},
        {"answer": "answer"},
        {"answer": "answer"},
        {"answer": "answer"},
        {"answer": "answer"}
    ],
    "explanation": "explanation"
}
```

What I should do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the right solution. I removed 'content' field and JSONSerializerField class and I started working on my json using [SerializerMethodField](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield).

```
class QuestionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    question = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    answers = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ('id', 'question', 'answers', 'explanation')

    def get_question(self, obj):
        return obj.json['question']

    def get_answers(self, obj):
        return obj.json['answers']
```

Answer (score 1):

you can make `content` write_only field and use it to just store data. Add two new read_only fields and use them to get data like:

```
class QuestionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    content = JSONSerializerField(source='json', write_only=True)
    question = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    answers = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ('id', 'content','question', 'answers', 'explanation')

    def get_questions(self, obj):
        return obj.content['question']

    def get_answers(self, obj):
        return obj.content['answers']
```

Comment: Thanks Anush! I just posted the right solution but I found it thanks to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should update your Field so that it returns / read the content directly:

```
class JSONSerializerField(serializers.Field):
    """ Serializer for JSONField -- required to make field writable"""
    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        return {'content': data}
    def to_representation(self, value):
        return value['content']
```